# PHPs ZipArchive drops empty directories

Tags: php, file, zip, php-ziparchive

## Problem

I am building an online file manager, for downloading a whole directory structure I am generating a zip file of all subdirectories and files (recursively), therefore I use the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.
It all works well, but empty directories are not in the generated zip file, although the dir is handled correctly. This is what i am currently using:

```
<?php
    $dirlist = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $filelist = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirlist, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open($tmpName, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        die();
    }
    foreach ($filelist as $key=>$value) {
        $result = false;
        if (is_dir($key)) {
            $result = $zip->addEmptyDir($key);
            //this message is correctly generated!
            DeWorx_Logger::debug('added dir '.$key .'('.$this->clearRelativePath($key).')');
        }
        else {
            $result = $zip->addFile($key, $key);
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
```

If I ommit the `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` I end up having a `.` **file** in all directories.

## Conclusion

The iterator works, the `addEmptyDir` call gets executed (the result is checked too!) correctly, creating a zip file with various zip tools works with empty directories as intendet.
Is this a bug in phps `ZipArchive` ([php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) lib or am I missing something? I don't want to end up creating dummy files just to keep the directory structure intact.

Comment: works ok for me on win7 and linux, both php 5.4.

Comment: just upgradet to php 5.4, it seems to work now. thank you!